# SDV CTGANSynthesizer generates AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' when trying to fit data

Tags: attributeerror, sdv

I am receiving an attribute error when trying to fit mock data using the CTGANSynthesizer from the SDV module. I am using SDV version 1.2.0 and Anaconda.

```
from sdv.datasets.demo import download_demo
from sdv.single_table import CTGANSynthesizer

real_data, metadata = download_demo(modality='single_table', 
dataset_name='fake_hotel_guests')
synthesizer = CTGANSynthesizer(metadata)
synthesizer.fit(data=real_data)
```

Generates the following error:

```
config = get_config().split()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Thanks in advance!